# ¿Cómo fijar notificaciones en el status bar?

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando un cronómetro y un temporizador que en ocasiones pueden tener activas hasta tres notificaciones, el problema viene cuando se actualizan, ya que se van moviendo constantemente hacia la parte superior de la barra de notificaciones. ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que cada vez que se actualicen se muevan hacia la parte superior?

Con el siguiente código creo las notificaciones desde distintos servicios, cada uno con un CHANNEL_ID y un NOTIFY_ID únicos.

```
 private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,getResources().getText(R.string.stopwatch_channel),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );

        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}

private Notification sendNotification(){
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.stopwatch)+" · "+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,min,secs))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stopwatch_24dp)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .build();

    return notification;
}

private void updateNotification() {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, sendNotification());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En este caso puedes usar el método **[setOngoing(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean)https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setOngoing(boolean))** de la clase [NotificationCompat.builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder)

Ejemplo:

```
...
...
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.stopwatch)+" · "+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hour,min,secs))
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stopwatch_24dp)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setShowWhen(false)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build();
...
...
```